# need to publish LaserScan topic

Tags: laser, naoqi, nao, hokuyo, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using NAO robot right now. And I need to get the laser data, but the current NAO stack doesn't provide that. The NAO that I use is NAO with laser head. The laser is Hokuyo URG-04LX.

I want to create node which publish LaserScan topic that I get from NaoQi SDK.
From the NaoQi, I can get this information :

- Min/Max Degree
- Min/Max Distance
- Array of Distance (size about : +/- 700)

Can I use that information to create the node that publish LaserScan topic ? If yes, can someone provide me the example of Hokuyo URG-04LX laser header, angle_increment, etc ?

If it is possible, I also want the example from the Hokuyo URG-04LX in the *.bag file.

Thank you :)

Update : thanks to the comment, I already can get the information via NaoQi SDK.

I put my code here, in case someone want to use it.

https://gist.github.com/rexcoder21/5957465

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66495/need-to-publish-laserscan-topic/) by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't have to use the NaoQi SDK. Hokuyo lasers are very well supported in ROS, due to their popularity. You can find documentation for the Hokuyo node [here](http://ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node). To use it, do the following:

```
rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node /dev/ttyACM0
```

If there are permission errors, run the below command and try the above again.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/ttyACM0
```

---

However, if you are interested in writing your own driver (understandable, for it's a good exercise), you need to publish the laser inside a `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` [message](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html).

In order to do so, you will need to fill in the header with the current ROS time and frame_id (probably `laser`).

You will need to fill in the `angle_min` and `angle_max` with the start and end angles of the scan with respect to the positive Z-axis. You will need to include the `angle_increment` and `scan_time` (time between scans).

Then, you will need to set the `range_min` and `range_max` to the shortest measurable distance and largest measurable distance respectively.

The next container is the ranges array. Fill the array with each individual range measurement from `angle_min` to `angle_max`. Then, the intensities (if provided). If your laser does not have intensities, then you may omit this array.

Best of luck!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on 2013-07-04**:
I see... but from the SDK I just can get this info :

- min degree & max degree
- min distance & max distance
- ranges array
  I don't know how to get the other information that I need to publish my own laser.
  Btw, I can't open NAO head to access hokuyo. They didn't give me the permission :(

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-07-04**:
I think you can get pretty much all that info from the datasheet of your laser, the most important thing that you need are the ranges array, which contain the actual measurements. the other fields are all static.

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-02-06**:
I have all the deatils.. How do I publish all of them together!?